# Read Xml String From DB in Classic Asp - odd return

Tags: xml, asp-classic

So I've got our legacy app which is classic asp and I've got a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ChangeRequests(
ChangeRequestsId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
XmlData nvarchar(max) NOT NULL)
```

Naturally "XmlData" has xml in it. The Xml string looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfControlData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ControlData>
    <Name>Email</Name>
    <Value>hosehead@bugger.com</Value>
  </ControlData>
  <ControlData>
    <Name>PreferredLanguage</Name>
    <Value>English</Value>
  </ControlData>
</ArrayOfControlData>
```

So when I do one of these:

```
select XmlData from ChangeRequests
```

I'd expect to get the above string back. Here's the bit of code I use that I expect results from:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "select XmlData from ChangeRequests", Conn

rs.MoveFirst
Response.Write rs("XmlData") & "<br />"
```

The result I get back is this cr4p:

```
Emailhosehead@bugger.comPreferredLanguageEnglish
```

Needless to say, I'd like the xml string back. I have a theory that the xml tag "" is a problem.

Just to cover any other assumptions made, I'm on MSSQL 2008 & IIS7.

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are missing all the XML tags and are only seeing the text nodes - are you viewing this in a browser as HTML? Did you do a view source to see if you are indeed only getting the text nodes?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting your full string back. The Response.Write may be sending it out with an HTML encoding, so the tags may be there, just not visible because they're unrecognized by the browser.

Comment: ahh cr4p. Yeah, it was correct from the start. I guess I needed the second pair (or third) pair of eyes. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you are actually getting the XML properly.

What you are probably doing is outputting it directly to a page, expecting it to render directly.

You can [HTMLEncode](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/met_htmlencode.asp) your XML in order for it to appear on the page:

```
Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(rs("XmlData")) & "<br />"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do the following.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write(rs("XmlData")
```